# SaveAsTextFile() results in Mkdirs failed - Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, permissions, cluster-computing, bigdata

Good, I currently have a cluster in spark with 3 working nodes. I also have a nfs server mounted on `/var/nfs` with `777` permission for testing. I'm trying to run the following code to count the words in a text:

```
root@master:/home/usuario# MASTER="spark://10.0.0.1:7077" spark-shell
val inputFile = sc.textFile("/var/nfs/texto.txt")
val counts = inputFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
counts.toDebugString
counts.cache()
counts.count()
counts.saveAsTextFile("/home/usuario/output");
```

But spark gives me the following error:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create
>   file:/var/nfs/output-4/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20170614094558_0007_m_000000_20
>   (exists=false, cwd=file:/opt/spark/work/app-20170614093824-0005/2)

I have searched for many websites but I can not find the solution for my case. All help is grateful.

Comment: Make sure the path exists in hdfs

Comment: @Wang What do you mean whit hdfs ??

Comment: People are asking about non-local mode running WITHOUT HDFS (i.e with NFS or even with only local volumes).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you start a spark-shell with MASTER as valid application-master url - and not `local[*]`, spark treats all paths as HDFS; and performs IO operations only in underlying HDFS; not in local.

YOu have mounted the locations in local file-system; and those paths are not existed in HDFS.

That's why, the error says: `exists=false`

Comment: When you start spark-shell with just : `spark-shell`, it, by-default, takes master as `LOCAL`, and then, spark uses local fs for IO operations.

Comment: What is the resolution for NFS (i.e. nonlocal)? This is not a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with me. 
 Check ownership of your directory again.

```
sudo chown -R owner-user:owner-group directory
```